# How to update partial view inside main view after Ajax post in ASP MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a main view with progress tracker on top, with links. On click of links I get partial view down. But, when I post the data, the partial view is not showing inside main view. How to achieve this?

```html
<div style="padding-top:2%">
   <ol class="progress-tracker">
       <li class="step"><a><span class="step-name active" onclick="javascript:showTab('@Url.Action("ReviewOrder","Tax")')" style="">Review order</span></a></li>
       <li class="step"><a><span class="step-name" onclick="javascript:showTab('@Url.Action("CreateAccount","Tax")')">Create account</span></a></li>
       <li class="step"><a><span class="step-name" onclick="javascript:showTab('Contract',this)">Contract</span></a></li>
   </ol>
</div>

function showTab(url) {

        $("#partialdiv").load(url, function (text, status, xhr) {

        });

    }
<div class="container">
    <div class="maincontainer" id="partialdiv" >

     //Partial View gets shown here on get request.Want to show the same partial view after post request

    </div>
</div>
```

How to have my partial view after post in main view inside the inner div?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the ajax for load the Partial View. that help to easy report that ajax is Loaded or not or Error reporting.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  data: {data: value}
  success: function (response) {
    $("#partialdiv").html(response);
    alert("Partial View is Loaded.....");
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
    // help to get error details
  }
});
```